# Заполните массив из N элементов случайными числами в интервале [1,N] ,чтобы обязательно вошли все числа от 1 до N (постройте случайную перестановку)

Tags: c++, массивы, случайные-числа, комбинаторика

Пример:
/
Массив:
3  2  1  4  5

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ..., N};

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());

std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
```

Comment: зачем unused данные?

Comment: @Maggot Почему - неиспользуемые? мы их перемешиваем. А вот в вашей правке - вы хотите перемешивать нули... Вот это уж точно - зачем?!

Comment: да - пошлючило что тут генерейт с mt а не шафл)

Comment: @Maggot Пошлючило - это уж как-то прямо слишком... по Фрейду... :)